# PHP: Как распознать цифры на изображении? (не капча)

Tags: php, распознавание

Как распознать цифры с такого изображения с помощью PHP?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шрифт всегда один и тот же, а вот кол-во символов может меняться от 2 до 5.

Comment: о! это ж номер порта на сайте с прокси :)

Answer (score 2):

Символы разделить очень просто. Заводите одномерный массив, размером равным ширине изображения. Теперь, суммируем по столбикам цвет (белый пиксель - ноль, черный - единица).

Там где промежуток между цифрами в результирующем массиве будет ноль. В других местах будет какое то число. Отрезав краевые нули, считаем кол-во внутренних нулевых групп (цифры могут разделятся не только одним пикселем, а и двумя-тремя). Это кол-во увеличим на 1 и получим кол-во цифр. Теперь можно делать "split". Путем нехитрых рассуждений, можно прийти к выводу, что по содержанию выделенных участков можно почти всегда идентифицировать цифру.

Как все это сделать "попроще". Если массив сделать строкой, ноль кодировать пробелом, а числа цифрами и буквами, то можно будет применять к нему строковые функции. trim для обрезки краевых пробелов. split - для раздерелие регуляркой на группы и тому подобное. Даже отладка сильно упрощается.

Например. Скорее всего единица в приведенной картинке будет кодироваться так "22711". ноль - "32223". Восьмерка - "33333".

Этот способ, если мне не изменяет память, называется "горизонтальная свертка изображения".

Comment: Хороший метод. Особенно часть с делением на столбцы.

Answer (score 2):

1. Выделить компоненты связности.
   Количество символов равно числу компонент связности. К счастью, цифр из нескольких компонент (как, например, бува "Ы" нет).
2. Смасштабировать компоненты связности к эталонному размеру.
   Для этого можно использовать встроенные средства масштабирования изображений.
3. Сравнить каждую компоненту с каждым из 10 эталонов попиксельно.
   Тот эталон, от которого меньше всего отклонений, является искомым.

Answer (score 0):

Есть, например, такой сервис [abbyy® cloud ocr sdk](http://ocrsdk.com/).

Цитата с сайта: *Free to develop, unlimited testing with sample images, pay only for production use.*

Есть примеры для [разных языков программирования](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/). в том числе и для [php](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/PHP).

Comment: Речь идет не о платных сервисах, которые найти не так уж и сложно, а о написании такого скрипта своими ручками. Есть скрипт, который распознает цифры с такого рисунка, но ему на вход нужно подавать кол-во изображенных символов, а оно всегда разное.

Comment: @LastChaos, так с какими проблемами вы столкнулись при написании кода?

Comment: Не знаю как определить кол-во изображенных символов на изображении.

Comment: деление ширины изображения на ширину символа не подходит?

Comment: Вы гений! Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Вот незадача - изображения всегда одинаковых размеров, независимо от кол-ва символов.

Comment: Решил проблему проверкой с конца изображения на наличие по пути черных пикселей, если он на пути встречается - прерываем цикл и имеем предопределенное кол-во символов, если же через 6 шагов(ширина символа 6 пикселей) на пути не появится ни 1-го символа - отнимаем 1 от предопределенного кол-ва и тд.