# На вход подается картинка игральной карты, как на выходе получить текст?

Tags: python, распознавание

[image: карта]

Как на выходе получить A-diamond? Не знаю почему, но pytesseract не может определить текст на такой картинке (уже все перепробовал)

Comment: Создайте словарь и идентифицируйте карты по ключу, это если карты заранее известны, если нет то это уже нужно смотреть в сторону компьютерного зрения

Comment: это зависит от того как другие карты могут выглядеть. Код новичка: [So I Suck At 24: Automating Card Games Using OpenCV and Python](http://arnab.org/blog/so-i-suck-24-automating-card-games-using-opencv-and-python)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429097/178988

Answer (score -1):

мне помогло использование `config`

```
config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'

card = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config)
```