# Распознание текста с картинки

Tags: c#, распознавание-символов

Как очень качественно распознать текст с помощью Tesseract или ему подобных ?

Подготавливаю (убираю общий фон) и скармливаю в Tesseract подобные картинки, шрифт один и тот же

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он делает массу ошибок( - добавляет ненужные пробелы, путает некоторые буквы, например `а` - `д`

А ради интереса скармливаю в яндекс ocr - так он даже мелкий шрифт иногда мне непонятный распознаёт верно. - но то онлайн вариант(((

Как правильно делать ? Может как то нужно обучить ? или ещё что ?

Comment: `Как очень качественно распознать текст с картинок` - мне кажется, это может быть темой научной диссертации :) Я к тому, что вопрос слишком большой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429136/178988